# The name "comportnumber" does not exist in the current contex

Tags: c#, scope

I decided to save all settings in SQL. 
In case I want to read for ex. comport from SQL DB and than  I got an error:
"c# the name "comportnumber" does not exist in the current contex"
What should I change to solve it ?

```
    SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = \\Program Files\\myprogram\\db.sdf; Password ='mypassword'");
        conn.Open();
            SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM [COMPORT]", conn);
            SqlCeDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                string comportnumber = rdr.GetString(0);
            }
        serialPort1.PortName = comportnumber;
        conn.Close();
        serialPort1.Close();
        if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
            serialPort1.Open();
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your question is that your comportnumber variable's scope was limited to the relatively small bracketed section in the while loop. Just move the declaration up.  But you have other issues as well - note how I restructured the code.

```
string comportnumber = "";
using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = \\Program Files\\myprogram\\db.sdf; Password ='mypassword'"))
using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM [COMPORT]", conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCeDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {    
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            comportnumber = rdr.GetString(0);
        }
    }
}
serialPort1.PortName = comportnumber;
serialPort1.Close();

if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
    serialPort1.Open();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have it, comportnumber only exists in the scope of the while loop. Try changing it to:

```
string comportnumber = string.Empty;
while (rdr.Read())
{
    comportnumber = rdr.GetString(0);
}
serialPort1.PortName = comportnumber;
```